# Why do I see "No SDK found" error when installing qt4-mac on Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, qt, macports

I'm seeing this error when I try to install Qt on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion developer preview.

```
ws5:1.4 nick$ sudo port install qt4-mac
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for qt4-mac
--->  Configuring qt4-mac
No SDK found in /Applications/Xcode44-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs for 10.8 ;  configure will probably fail. 
  Please install Apple's Developer Tools again.
```

Answer (score 2):

With XCode 4.4 developer preview, using this seems to work, though I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode44-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/ /Applications/Xcode44-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs
```

The warning seems to go away after I create this link.